# OpenGL Android app tests with Robotium

Tags: android, opengl-es, robotium

I am doing a game for Android which uses C++ and OpenGL. I would like to do some automated testing with Robotium, but I could not find any information about this. There is any way to do tests that make touches on some concrete x/y position from screen? And as the game can work on different resolutions, how can be obtained this x/y position in variable resolutions?

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use click(int x, int y) from the UiDevice class of the UIAutomator tool.

So, firstly you create your new test case, that extends UiAutomatorTestCase, get the UiDevice:

```
device = getUiDevice();
device.click(200,200);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Robotium there is a method: clickOnScreen(int x, int y) that you can use to click on a specific coordinate.